# How to determine if an assembly name matches a requested, partial assembly name

Tags: c#, .net

In my application, I want to test if any entry in a given list of assemblies qualifies as a requested assembly name.

Due to the structure of my application, I had to provide some mechanism to aid the application in assembly loading (as described in [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908).
The article has kind of an interesting way of determining if a loaded assembly qualifies for the request.

```
if(strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(","))==args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")))
```

This approach causes problems for me when the supplied assembly name is only only the name, because args.Name does not contain a `,`:

```
private Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve( object sender, ResolveEventArgs args ) {
  foreach( Assembly pluginAssembly in LoadedPluginAssemblies ) {
    if( pluginAssembly.FullName.Substring( 0, pluginAssembly.FullName.IndexOf( "," ) ) == args.Name.Substring( 0, args.Name.IndexOf( "," ) ) ) {
      return pluginAssembly;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Works**:

```
MyApp.JobDetails, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException**:

```
MyApp.JobDetails
```

Obviously, I could just refine the string matching until it works as I need it, but isn't there a *better* way to handle this? How am I supposed to know when a given assembly is a valid match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably like to use the  [AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.referencematchesdefinition%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName( args.Name );
foreach( Assembly pluginAssembly in LoadedPluginAssemblies ) {
  if( AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition( name, pluginAssembly.GetName() ) ) 
    return pluginAssembly;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.IndexOf` returns -1 if no mtach is found. Use `String.Split` instead.

```
private Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve( object sender, ResolveEventArgs args ) { 
    foreach( Assembly pluginAssembly in LoadedPluginAssemblies ) { 
        if( pluginAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] == args.Name.Split(',')[0]) { 
            return pluginAssembly; 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) class. You can create objects from a full or partial assembly name via the AssemblyName(string) c'tor and compare them via the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.name.aspx) property.

```
    AssemblyName partial = new AssemblyName("MyApp.JobDetails");
    AssemblyName full = new AssemblyName("MyApp.JobDetails, Version=1.0.0.2001, Culture=en-US, PublicToken=null");
    bool isMatch = String.Compare(partial.Name, full.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
```